# Failed to import Cloud Firestore library for Python

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create a python script to fetch data from my Cloud Firestore database.
But I get this weird error:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore

Exception has occurred: ImportError
Failed to import the Cloud Firestore library for Python. Make sure to install the "google-cloud-firestore" module.
  File "C:\Users\Alexandru\Desktop\python\hello.py", line 10, in <module>
    from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore
```

And I think I installed all packages

```
pip list
    
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
Package                  Version
------------------------ ----------
astroid                  2.4.1
autopep8                 1.5.3
CacheControl             0.12.6
cachetools               4.1.0
certifi                  2020.4.5.1
cffi                     1.14.0
chardet                  3.0.4
colorama                 0.4.3
cryptography             2.9.2
firebase                 3.0.1
firebase-admin           4.3.0
google-api-core          1.18.0
google-api-python-client 1.9.1
google-auth              1.16.1
google-auth-httplib2     0.0.3
google-cloud-core        1.3.0
google-cloud-firestore   1.7.0
google-cloud-storage     1.28.1
google-resumable-media   0.5.1
googleapis-common-protos 1.52.0
grpcio                   1.29.0
httplib2                 0.18.1
idna                     2.9
isort                    4.3.21
jwcrypto                 0.7
lazy-object-proxy        1.4.3
mccabe                   0.6.1
msgpack                  1.0.0
pip                      20.1.1
protobuf                 3.12.2
pyasn1                   0.4.8
pyasn1-modules           0.2.8
pycodestyle              2.6.0
pycparser                2.20
pylint                   2.5.2
python-firebase          1.2
python-jwt               3.2.6
pytz                     2020.1
requests                 2.23.0
rsa                      4.0
setuptools               41.2.0
six                      1.15.0
toml                     0.10.1
uritemplate              3.0.1
urllib3                  1.25.9
wrapt                    1.12.1
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please do not share pictures of code and text.  Copy the text into the question itself, and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question

Comment: Can you share the output of pip list

Comment: I added the pip list too

Answer (score 3):

Somehow I issue the following commands and it also worked for me:

```sh
$ pip3 install --upgrade pip
$ python3 -m pip install --upgrade setuptools
$ pip3 install --no-cache-dir --force-reinstall -Iv grpcio==1.45
```

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall pip, it worked for me :

```
python -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip
```